# How to know the size of a package

Tags: command-line, package-management, software-installation, files

Lets say I want to install the gcc package using `sudo apt-get install gcc` but before I want to know the size of it, is there a command for that ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you run

```
sudo apt install gcc
```

you will get a prompt showing the packages to be installed and required space, asking if you want to continue.

To see the download size of a specific package you can run e.g.

```
apt show gcc
```